# Oracle APEX 5 - modal region not opening after page submit

Tags: javascript, checkbox, modal-dialog, oracle-apex-5

OK, here's my situation.  I have modal region with a chart.  There are checkboxes corresponding to each line on the chart.  I want the end user to be able to click a checkbox and have the corresponding line on the chart appear/disappear.  Here's where I am:

1. User opens page two
2. There is a button "open chart" at the top of the page
3. When that is pressed, chart opens
4. User hits a checkbox, the page is submitted with a dynamic action
5. The modal region disappears
6. When I open the modal region back up, the line has indeed disappeared like it was supposed to.

My problem is number 5 above.  I need that modal region to stay open after the dynamic action on the checkbox submits the page.

So far, I have tried another action (under the submit page on checkbox change action) that opens the modal region.  But, that isn't working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: There's not really any code to put in the question... It's Oracle APEX 5 (the tags I put in with the question).  Also, I thought I was putting the specific problem and desired behavior with "My problem is number 5 above.  I need that modal region to stay open after the dynamic action on the checkbox submits the page."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer.  The solution was to forget about the modal **region** and make a modal **page**.  Now, when I check/uncheck a box, I can call a dynamic action to resubmit the **modal page** without it disappearing.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you used the wizard to build the page then it's likely that when you submit the page the close dialog process is being triggered. In that case, to stop that from happening either delete the process or put a condition on it (request contained in value) and select the buttons you want to close it.

Comment: Ah!  I see what you are saying and I need to add more information.  This is a modal **region** within my page.  Within Page 1, there is a button, "Chart" that opens the modal region by firing the javascript code "openModal('Chart1');"  This is just the protocol my co-worker and I use to make modal windows appear on the page.